# SVGからpng変換する際に<use>タグが反映されない

Tags: c#, svg

SVGからPNGに変換する際にuseタグを使用している下図赤い四角が反映されません。
[image: 左：SVG/右：PNG]

C#

```
using SVG;

public void SVGtoPNG(string svgFilePath)
{
    var svgDocument = SvgDocument.Open(svgFilePath);
    var bitmap = svgDocument.Draw();
    bitmap.Save(@"C:\SVGtoPNG\image.png", System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png);
}
```

SVG

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"  xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="1300" height="700" class="mainsvg ng-isolate-scope" viewBox="0 0 1920 1080" xml:space="preserve" enable-background="new 0 0 1920 1080" id="svgcontent" overflow="visible" x="252" y="27" point-binding-updated="" graphics-version="3.0" style="" viewer-directive="" avb-updated="" point-override-icon-position-updated="" status-summary-rect-removed="">
  <defs style="pointer-events: inherit">
    <linearGradient id="svg_11">
      <stop stop-color="#56aaff" stop-opacity="1" offset="0.47265625" />
      <stop stop-color="#56ffff" stop-opacity="0.99609375" offset="0.75390625" />
    </linearGradient>
    <svg xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="150" height="150" viewBox="0 0 150 22.5 " avbwidth="150" obj-id="advance_value_box" sample-exclude-from-measure="text" x="0" y="0" id="svg_01"  class="ng-isolate-scope" style="cursor: default;">
      <g open-command-dialog="" class="advbox-ExpCol" style="pointer-events:visible" make-cursor-pointer="true" id="svg_342">
        <rect rx="2" ry="2" id="advBox_svg_191" class="avb-bg-rect" height="20.5" width="148.5" y="1" x="1" stroke="grey" fill="#FF0000" />
      </g>
    </svg>
  </defs>
  <masterlayertoggleindicator id="masterLayerIndicator" isenable="true" isenabledinviewer="true" style="pointer-events: inherit" />
  <g style="pointer-events:all" custom-temp-title="Background" opacity="1" display="inline">
    <title style="pointer-events:inherit" layer-name="BackgroundText">Background</title>
    <image x="0" y="-0" width="1923" height="1196" id="svg_95" xlink:href="data:image/png;base64,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" fill-opacity="0.65" style="pointer-events:inherit" />
  </g>
  <g style="pointer-events:all" data-layer-index="1" opacity="1" custom-temp-title="DataBox" display="inline">
    <title style="pointer-events:inherit">DataBox</title>
    <use id="svg_01-1" xlink:href="#svg_01" data-issymbol="true" x="200" y="200" opacity="1" is-point-binded="true" maxmappedattrindex="1" maxmappedattrindex_x="0" maxmappedattrindex_y="1" symbol-name="NewAdvanceValueBox" symbol-title="BasicSymbols" key-data-sequence="[{'useId':''}]" style="pointer-events:inherit" />
  </g>
  <desc></desc>
</svg>
```

いろいろ調べてみましたがそれらしい情報がないため、原因、その他方法ご存知の方がいらっしゃいましたら、ご教授お願い致します。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Magick.NETで変換すると、出力されました。
[Magick.NET-Q16-AnyCPU](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Magick.NET-Q16-AnyCPU/8.3.2?_src=template)

```cs
using ImageMagick;

using (var img = new MagickImage("c:/test/test.svg"))
{
    img.Write("c:/test/test.png", MagickFormat.Png);
}
```

[image: サンプル画像]

Answer (score 0):

こちらの記事が該当するようです。
つまり`<use>`しようとする元の`svg`エレメントの定義の仕方が違うということなのでしょう。
[How to reuse an embedded SVG element in the same page?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34225008/9014308)

> `symbol` + `use` + `href="#symbol-id"`
>
> to define a symbol once, and use it in other svg documents
>
> ...以下は省略

他にMDNの記述：
[<symbol>](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/symbol)
[<use>](https://developer.mozilla.org/ja/docs/Web/SVG/Element/use)

日本語記事：
[useタグとsymbolタグを使ってsvgを使いまわしてみた。](https://littlethings.jp/blog/web/svg-icon)
[SVGのsymbol、use要素とviewBox属性の挙動](https://www.1915keke.com/entry/2018/10/11/160640)

なので以下の部分の`svg`を：

```
    <svg xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="150" height="150" viewBox="0 0 150 22.5 " avbwidth="150" obj-id="advance_value_box" sample-exclude-from-measure="text" x="0" y="0" id="svg_01"  class="ng-isolate-scope" style="cursor: default;">
      <g open-command-dialog="" class="advbox-ExpCol" style="pointer-events:visible" make-cursor-pointer="true" id="svg_342">
        <rect rx="2" ry="2" id="advBox_svg_191" class="avb-bg-rect" height="20.5" width="148.5" y="1" x="1" stroke="grey" fill="#FF0000" />
      </g>
    </svg>
```

以下のように`symbol`に変えることでSVG.NETのサンプル[SVG/Samples/SVGViewer/](https://github.com/svg-net/SVG/tree/master/Samples/SVGViewer)でも「赤い四角」が表示されました。

```
    <symbol xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="150" height="150" viewBox="0 0 150 22.5 " avbwidth="150" obj-id="advance_value_box" sample-exclude-from-measure="text" x="0" y="0" id="svg_01"  class="ng-isolate-scope" style="cursor: default;">
      <g open-command-dialog="" class="advbox-ExpCol" style="pointer-events:visible" make-cursor-pointer="true" id="svg_342">
        <rect rx="2" ry="2" id="advBox_svg_191" class="avb-bg-rect" height="20.5" width="148.5" y="1" x="1" stroke="grey" fill="#FF0000" />
      </g>
    </symbol>
```

---

ただしSVGの準拠版数も関係しているようですね。
上記参照記事の回答のソースには、`svg`タグすべてに`version="2.0"`が入っていますし、回答の最後の方に以下の記述があります。

> for svg version 1.1 we need `<svg version="1.1" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">` and `<use xlink:href="#some-id"/>`

しかしながら、SVG.NETでの旧版数指定の方法は対処されていないようです。
`svg`タグに`version="1.1"`を追加しても「赤い四角」表示はされませんでした。
更には旧版数用らしい`xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"`と`xlink:`の記述は、有っても無くても動作に影響は無いようですので、その部分はチグハグな感じです。